# Menu active with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu

Best regard,

I have a menu and i want to use the active class `active` with url format but I don't know how:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="menul">
        <a href="#">
            <div>
                <img src="image"  alt="">
                <span class="sombra"></span>
                <img class="onhover" src="image"  alt="image">
            </div>
        </a>    
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(".menul a").each(function() {   
    if (this.href == window.location.href)
        $(.onhover).addClass("active");
})
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is meaning of `active class "active" with url format`? Explain more about your purpose

Answer (score 0):

try to implement with navbar nav class example below

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="img"  alt="">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="img"  alt="image">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```